# Negative height value error for bar graph in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm coming across an error in my code in which the height, calculated in this code,:

```
height: function (d) {
                    console.log( d.value);
                    return canvas.height - MARGINS.top - d.value;
                }
```

where the height ends up being negative and therefore invalid because the "d.value" is larger than the height. I don't really understand why this is happening and would really appreciate some help.

Full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/1uo0xz93/3/

Answer (score 1):

The fix to this question can be found by using the abs() function. When the values from the bar graph went below zero, the program would mess up. Since I am trying to graph positive integer numbers, it is therefore necessary to make said integers positive. Doing so resulted in a successful run and ideal results.

Comment: Usually you would use a D3 scale and not the raw value. Then you don't run into problems like this.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Actually, I was using a d3 scale, but for some reason the negative numbers were really big on the scale